# How can I scale down the width of images in bulk that are embedded in posts throughout the site?

Tags: theme-development, post-thumbnails, images

I am building a new WordPress theme and it is quite different from my current theme. Currently the dimensions of my images are much wider than how I would like them to be for my new theme I am developing. Is there way to scale down the widths programmatically and in mass? Is there a plugin that accomplishes this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if what you need is to apply this to big images (no thumbnails like in Gembel's solution) you can use CSS, including a max-width statement. For example:

```
.content img{width:98%; max-width:200px;}
```

of course you should adapt the numbers to what you need, but you'll get the idea

Answer (score 0):

this plugin can handle  your problem http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/